# Need help with VB.NET List Logic

Tags: vb.net, list, loops

Hey guys, so I am creating a List(Of String), always of size 9.

This list contains True/False values. I need to go through this list and find the 3 values that are True (will never be more than 3, but could be less) and then set 3 string values in my code to the 3 index's of those values + 1.

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub SetDenialReasons(ByVal LoanData As DataRow)
        Dim reasons As New List(Of String)
        With reasons
            .Add(LoanData.Item("IsDenialReasonDTI").ToString)
            .Add(LoanData.Item("IsDenialReasonEmploymentHistory").ToString)
            .Add(LoanData.Item("IsDenialReasonCreditHistory").ToString)
            .Add(LoanData.Item("IsDenialReasonCollateral").ToString)
            .Add(LoanData.Item("IsDenialReasonCash").ToString)
            .Add(LoanData.Item("IsDenialReasonInverifiableInfo").ToString)
            .Add(LoanData.Item("IsDenialReasonIncomplete").ToString)
            .Add(LoanData.Item("IsDenialReasonMortgageInsuranceDenied").ToString)
            .Add(LoanData.Item("IsDenialReasonOther").ToString)
        End With

        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For Each item As String In reasons
            If item = "True" Then
                count += 1
            End If
        Next

        If count = 1 Then
            DenialReason1 = (reasons.IndexOf("True") + 1).ToString
        ElseIf count = 2 Then
            DenialReason1 = (reasons.IndexOf("True") + 1).ToString
            DenialReason2 = (reasons.LastIndexOf("True") + 1).ToString
        ElseIf count >= 3 Then
            Dim tempIndex As Integer = reasons.IndexOf("True")
            DenialReason1 = (reasons.IndexOf("True") + 1).ToString
            DenialReason2 = (reasons.IndexOf("True", tempIndex, reasons.Count - 1) + 1).ToString
            DenialReason3 = (reasons.LastIndexOf("True") + 1).ToString
        End If
    End Sub
```

I had 3 True's next to each other in the array and the code failed with an exception saying count must be positive or something.

Now if there are less than 3 True's, it should set the remaining DenialReason's that haven't been set yet as blank (however they are set as blank in the constructor already to account for this).

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? If 3.5 or greater, you can solve this by using LINQ.

Comment: It is 3.5 however I cannot use LINQ.

Comment: It looks like you might keep around OLD values of DenialReason 2 or 3.

Comment: can you use extension methods?

Comment: Don't know what extension methods are. My bad we're actually in .NET 2.0. @gbogumil -- what do you mean?

Comment: It seems to only break (or just not work correctly), when count >= 3. Other two scenarios seem to work fine.

Comment: If you have three reasons in the first run, then one reason in the second run then DenialReason2 and 3 'may' still have their values from the first run.  You might want to set them back to a default value before each evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could modify your `For Each` code to handle the assignment of the `DenialReason`s.  This still feels like a hack, but I think it may be cleaner that what you have.  If you use this code, you don't need the code that begins with `If count = 1...`:

```
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim index As Integer = 1
    For Each item As String In reasons
        If item = "True" Then
            count += 1
            Select Case count
                Case 1
                    DenialReason1 = index.ToString()
                Case 2
                    DenialReason2 = index.ToString()
                Case 3
                    DenialReason3 = index.ToString()
            End Select
        End If
        index += 1
    Next
```

The `index` variable above assumes a 1-based index.  I think this is cleaner than using `IndexOf()`.

I think a better solution might be to have a list of `DenialReason`s and add to that list as items are true:

```
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim index As Integer = 1
    Dim denialReasons As New List(Of String)()
    For Each item As String In reasons
        If item = "True" Then
            denialReasons.Add(index)
        End If
        index += 1
    Next
```

Then you can simply iterate through your list of `denialReasons`. This is flexible so that if, for whatever reason, you have more than three `DenialReason`s, you don't have to add another hard-coded variable.